# Image not showing correctly after rotation

Tags: css, vue.js

I need to rotate an image by 90ded and show it in a Card Component, right now I'm using [Element.io](https://element.eleme.io/2.1/#/en-US/component/card), but when I rotate the image, it covers part of the text

Currently, the image only has this style:

```css
.image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

which works fine when we only want to show the original image

Here is a reproduction of my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/HugoLiconV/92hspw56/

Comment: So you want the text to be pushed down?

Comment: yes, I want it to look exactly like it would look without rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of solved it. We are using cloudinary, so what I did was to add a transformation to rotate the image by adding a_90 to the link, for example: `http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/a_90/v1569337519/test.png`

Comment: Great to hear that Hugo, now click the mark (tick) and mark your answer as correct so future users who have similar issues can refer to this answer of yours. Well done buddy!